# How do I create a next button that does 3 different functions at different times?

Tags: javascript, collada

I'm trying to do 3 different scenes in colada, and I don't know how to make one button move through the scenes. Please help!

So right now I have three buttons

```
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick="a();">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick="b();"> 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick="c();">3</a>
```

But I want to only have 1 button that can go through the 3 functions. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` when scene changes or just use one event listener, keep a global variable of "current scene" and execute logic based on that variable, i.e `if (scene === 1) {} else if (scene === 2) {} else {}`.

Comment: I have three scenes, each their own function. Is that right so far?